Grafana session expiry issue
"I need assistance in enabling the grafana_session_expiry to be HttpOnly. Your help would be greatly appreciated. The provided image illustrates the requirement to activate the flag on Grafana session expiry. Any assistance rendered in achieving this objective would be highly valued."(https://i.sstatic.net/V0uPLOCt.png)
the above image as shows i need to enable the flag on Grafana session expiry any help would be appreciated (https://i.sstatic.net/ylQvLg0w.png)
Please let me know if anyone has the solution for the above problem.
Please let me know if anyone has the solution for the above problem.
